# How would you take an ADB logcat without RSA fingerprint present and during first boot of rom?

Tags: android, android-logcat, rom

I am trying to port MIUI v6 to my phone (and no this thread is NOT about porting ROM, please read ahead).

First, its on **Android 4.4.4**

*Now for problem->*

It gets stuck on bootloop and I would like to know the cause. Now I do know how to take logcats using adb, but for some reason adb logcat doesnt detect phone during its bootanimation (and it doesnt go beyond bootanimation being it a bootloop). I am guessing it must have something to do with RSA fingerprint since there is no such key present being in/during the very first boot.

I have tried adding this to build.prop->

```
ro.debuggable=1
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
ro.adb.secure=0
```

But even that doesnt work. Now my **base rom is CM 11 with default CM kernel**. Since both rom and kernel are rooted, they are easily eligible to take a logcat during first boot.

At first I thought that it could be a miui rom-port problem. So I tested it with just CM simple rom installed. Ofcourse it booted fine and everything was fine, but even then I was unable to take logcat for first boot (it just doesn't "recognize" device until that RSA fingerprint authentication is accepted. I tested after adding the authentication and then it logged the boot just fine).

In addition to this, I have also attempted to pull last kernel message or `kmsg`, but I am unable to even pull that.

Finally, I also tried using init script. I added script to `system/etc/init.d/` and the script had the following content:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
mount -o rw,remount "/system"
logcat > /sdcard/log.txt
```

Now this script does create a file, but that file is blank. No text at all.

So to sum it all, how can I take a logcat for very first boot without RSA fingerprint added? Any method goes. Even if I can make it store log in any partition anywhere, I can attempt to pull that log using `adb pull`. But for now, its not working.